# How to make the changes by an app on another app permanent

Tags: android-emulator

How to make values changed by an of another app permanent.
I have this app that changes some values of bluestacks emulator and makes it undetectable, I also have a thord party software that runs in the background and modifies my game to improve my gameplay so it tampers with the game. Is there any way to make these two permanent?

I have no idea how to do this.